# How to get in Wonder Tower after explosion?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I completed the main campaign of Batman Arkham City.

Now looking at the map, I have 2 riddles remaining on Wonder Tower, but I can't find a way up after the explosion.

Do I lose access to these riddles?

Comment: You might want to re-upload to stack.imgur the image currently hosted on imageshack, as it's been transformed into an ad. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You enter the same way as you did the first time, i.e. go through Wonder City and take the elevator. You won't be able to access the topmost part of the tower, but there are no collectibles that far up. All trophies, riddles and breakable items are still reachable after completing the main campaign.

Comment: The perspective riddle on the outside of the tower *does* require you to be pretty far up.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: Yes, but even that one can be done by climbing as far up as possible, gliding off the tower and trying to align the question mark mid flight. It took me a few tries, but it's definitely doable.

Comment: Yes did it in mid flight. :) Anyway I am at 75% of the secondary mission of the Riddler... It's getting hard to find the last enigma/trophee

Comment: @Hammar you are saving me, if you can give a look at this http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45047/where-can-i-find-eletricty-for-this-trophee-of-batman

Comment: You can access the top of the tower, it just takes a bit of timing. @Marshall's answer has it right. However, there's nothing to do up there but explore; no collectibles. Basically just wandering around.

Answer (score 1):

Once on the beam tht has a tight rope instead of just grappling and trying to use the vent (which is now blocked off) use grapnel boost from the beam, glide off the center pillar back out the door, curve right just a hair you will we the R1 symbol for a split second (literally it flashes at the top of screen so fast it's barely noticeable) hit it just right and u will grapnel to a ledge from there u can get to the gargoyles and o what ever

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can stay on the antennae before walking the tightrope and mash RT (throwing continuous freeze grenades.) You will begin to float and ascend upward; ascend until you see RB. Tap it and catch a gargoyle. Home free buddy. 
Fly down n stay in the air for achievement!