# Where can I find electricity for this fuse box?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

The position on the map is:

http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1189/senzatitolo2g.jpg

the screen is:

http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/1589/senzatitolo1jci.jpg

I can't find electricity for it though.

### Also

I need the electricity for this:

http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/5522/senzatitolo3p.jpg

I saw one source of power on the far right side of metro, but it's seriously too far away.

Comment: You might want to re-upload to stack.imgur the image currently hosted on imageshack, as it's been transformed into an ad. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your REC to activate both of these fuse boxes

Comment: OH my god didn't know it before

Comment: Hehe it took me about an hour to figure that one out too ^_^

Answer (score 0):

There's some things you can do here that may or may not work.

1. The more obvious thing: You use the **Remote Electrical Charge** on the boxes. Should be easy enough. The Remote Electrical Charge is the item you use around the beginning of the game in the Loading Bay, I believe.
2. You use the **Remote Control Batarang** to allow it to enter the current of electricity you mentioned, and then make it hit the boxes. Since this is MUCH more time-consuming, try #1 first.

Best of luck.